# Javascript navigation with array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a navigation that chagnes the background of a div using the array data.

It isn't working like I would want it.

I'm trying to use `if` inside `addEventListener` with 'click' function.

```js
  
var designNextBg = document.getElementById('js-nextbg');
var designBg = document.getElementById('js-designBg');
var designBgArray = [
  'url(images/ipb.png)',
  'url(images/ipg.png)',
  'url(images/ipr.png)',
  'url(images/ipw.png)',
  'url(images/ipy.png)'
];
var positionBg = document.getElementById('js-positionBg');
var i = 0;

designNextBg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (i = 0) {
    designBg.style.backgroundImage = designBgArray[i];
    i = i + 1;
    positionBg.innerHTML = "0" + (i + 1) + "/05";
    return i;
  } else if (i = 4) {
    designBg.style.backgroundImage = designBgArray[i];
    i = 0;
    positionBg.innerHTML = "0" + (i + 1) + "/05";
    return i;
  } else {
    designBg.style.backgroundImage = designBgArray[i];
    i = i + 1;
    positionBg.innerHTML = "0" + (i + 1) + "/05";
    return i;
  };
});
```

```html
<div id="js-designBg" class="design-bg">
  <div class="design-navigation">
    <span id="js-positionBg">01/05</span>
    <p>
      <a id="js-prevbg" class="angle-buttons"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
      <a id="js-nextbg" class="angle-buttons"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How it is not working like you want it to? What is the bug?

Comment: With this code when i press the prev button it changes to 04/05 and images/ipy.png. After this when i press the 'next' button the bg doesn't change and the span goes to 01/05

Comment: **if (i = 0)** should probably be **if (i === 0)**, and **else if (i = 4)** should probably be **else if (i === 4)**. Might be that will fix your problem. **===** is a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) whereas **=** is an assignment operator.

Comment: @MoirexCax Please [edit] the desired behavior from your comment into the Question itself. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18447222)

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp that accualy helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

your code is way to complicated. I've added two ways to deal with `i` and keep it inside the bounds. For once, you can do this in the click-handler *(currently commented out)*, or you can just continuously increment/decrement there and compute the actual index inside the array with a oneliner.

```js
var designBg = document.getElementById('js-designBg');
var designBgArray = [
  'url(images/ipb.png)',
  'url(images/ipg.png)',
  'url(images/ipr.png)',
  'url(images/ipw.png)',
  'url(images/ipy.png)'
];
var positionBg = document.getElementById('js-positionBg');
var i = 0;

var nextButton = document.getElementById('js-nextbg');
var prevButton = document.getElementById('js-prevbg');

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  //if(++i === designBgArray.length) i=0;
  ++i;
  updateView();
});

prevButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  //if(--i < 0) i += designBgArray.length;
  --i;
  updateView();
});


function lz(nr){//a simple leading zero function
  return String(nr).padStart(2, 0);
}

funciton updateView(){
  var len = designBgArray.length;
  //get i back into the boundaries
  //you could also take care of that in the click-handler
  //but this way, it's all in one place
  var index = i%len + (i<0? len: 0);
  
  designBg.style.backgroundImage = designBgArray[index];
  positionBg.textContent = lz(index+1) + "/" + lz(len);
}
```

```html
<div id="js-designBg" class="design-bg">
  <div class="design-navigation">
    <span id="js-positionBg">01/05</span>
    <p>
      <a id="js-prevbg" class="angle-buttons"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
      <a id="js-nextbg" class="angle-buttons"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MoirexCax, you mean the displayed index, just updated that. It's this line: `positionBg.textContent = lz(index+1) + "/" + lz(len);`

Answer (score 1):

This code works for 'NEXT' button with changing background colours replace backgroundImage as per requirement

```js
  
var designNextBg = document.getElementById('js-nextbg');
var designBg = document.getElementById('js-designBg');
   var designBgArray = [
  'red',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'yellow',
  'cyan'
];    var positionBg = document.getElementById('js-positionBg');
var i = 0;

designNextBg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (i == 0) {
    designBg.style.background = designBgArray[i];
    i = i + 1;
    positionBg.innerHTML = "0" + (i + 1) + "/05";
    return i;
  } else if (i == 4) {
    designBg.style.background = designBgArray[i];
    i = 0;
    positionBg.innerHTML = "0" + (i + 1) + "/05";
    return i;
  } else {
    designBg.style.background = designBgArray[i];
    i = i + 1;
    positionBg.innerHTML = "0" + (i + 1) + "/05";
    return i;
  };
});
```

```html
<div id="js-designBg" class="design-bg">
  <div class="design-navigation">
    <span id="js-positionBg">01/05</span>
    <p>
    
      <input type ='button' value ='NEXT' id="js-nextbg" class="angle-buttons">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
designNextBg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (i = 0) {
    designBg.style.backgroundImage = designBgArray[i];
    i = i + 1;
    positionBg.innerHTML = "0" + (i + 1) + "/05";
    return i;
  } else if (i = 4) {
    designBg.style.backgroundImage = designBgArray[i];
    i = 0;
    positionBg.innerHTML = "0" + (i + 1) + "/05";
    return i;
  } else {
    designBg.style.backgroundImage = designBgArray[i];
    i = i + 1;
    positionBg.innerHTML = "0" + (i + 1) + "/05";
    return i;
  };
});
```

Here, inside `if` you must give `==` or `===` for comparison. `=` means assignment operator which always returns `true`. So `i=0` returns `true` and always the first condition gets passed. So it returns `1`. So it changes the span to `01/05`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your code and [*answer posted by Thomas*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136174/javascript-navigation-with-array/48136423#48136423) I would provide a working example instead of blank screen and nonexistent background.

> Introduced minor code improvements for easier reading, service logic isolation and less letters.

```js
/**
 * List of random images
 * @type {Array}
 */
var designBgArray = [
  'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/201/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/202/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/203/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/204/300'
];

var getEl = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  },
  addClick = function(el, fn) {
    el.addEventListener('click', fn);
  },
  lz = function(nr) {
    return String(nr).padStart(2, 0);
  };

var designBg = getEl('js-designBg'),
  positionBg = getEl('js-positionBg'),
  nextButton = getEl('js-nextbg'),
  prevButton = getEl('js-prevbg');

var render = function() {
  var len = designBgArray.length,
    index = i % len + (i < 0 ? len : 0);

  console.log('Rendering "i"', i);

  designBg.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+designBgArray[index]+')';
  positionBg.textContent = lz(index+1) + "/" + lz(len);
};

var i = 0;

render(); // Initial background set (if blank bg is not applicable)

addClick(nextButton, function(e) {
  i++;

  if (i === designBgArray.length + 1) {
    i = 0;
  }

  render();
});

addClick(prevButton, function(e) {
  i--;

  if (i < 1) {
    i = designBgArray.length;
  }

  render();
});
```

```css
.angle-buttons, #js-positionBg {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="js-designBg" class="design-bg">
  <div class="design-navigation">
    <span id="js-positionBg">01/05</span>
    <p>
      <a id="js-prevbg" class="angle-buttons">&lt;</a>
      <a id="js-nextbg" class="angle-buttons">&gt;</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great. With `lz(index+1)` the span is displaying correctly.